# How to add disable_web_page_preview telegram bot node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

Good evening friends, first of all apologies for my English.

I am coding in nodejs and I would like to add the **disable_web_page_preview** in the code, but I can't and I don't know where to add it.

Telegram.prototype.sendIn = async function(color, clientId, protection = false, gale = false){
if(!color || !clientId)
return { status: "error", message: "cor e id do chat são argumentos obrigatorios" }

```
let message = [];

if(gale)
    message.push(`⚠️ <b>Aviso de Gale ${gale}:</b>\n`);
else
    message.push(`<b>Sinal Confirmado</b>\n`);
    
    message.push(`⏩ Entre no: ${this._getColorNameOrEmoticon(color, true)} ${this._getColorNameOrEmoticon(color, false, true)}`);
    if(typeof protection === "number")
        message.push(`Proteção no ${this._getColorNameOrEmoticon(protection, true)} ${this._getColorNameOrEmoticon(protection, false, true)}\n`);
        message.push(`⏩ Com proteção no: ⚪`);
        message.push(`<a href="https://blaze.com/pt/games/double" title="https://blaze.com/pt/games/double" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="text-entity-link" dir="auto">⏩ Aposte aqui</a>`);
        
    return await this.send(message.join('\n'), clientId, { parse_mode: "HTML"} );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the options for `sendMessage()` method. You can read all the available options in the [Telegram Bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage). It can be done by adding `disable_web_page_preview: true`.

```
return await this.send(message.join('\n'), clientId, { parse_mode: "HTML", disable_web_page_preview: true } );
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I had done that, but I was putting it like this:

return await this.send(message.join('\n'), clientId, { parse_mode: "HTML", disable_web_page_preview: "true" } );